# Grafana replace Variables

Tags: prometheus, grafana, exporter

I would like some help with replacing variable values. I'm using Grafana + Cloudwatch Exporter.

I'm collecting metrics from aws DMS. When I run: label_values(replication_task_identifier) i have output: **5YUKKRZ6G5RYDW6UDR4** and **75UKQGIYYJMORPCMXP5T4.

The logic would be: **These IDS are task names. would need to replace 5YUKKRZ6G5RYDW6UDR4 per task-prod and 75UKQGIYYJMORPCMXP5T4 per task-prod-v1.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

I'm starting on grafana now.

Comment: Are these values constant over time? If not what are the rules to connect one of those with semantic name?

Comment: YES, they are AWS DMS tasks.

Whenever a new task is generated it appears. The query "label_values ​​(replication_task_identifier)" returns the task ids.

Comment: And what is your exact goal here? Show 'task-prod' and 'task-prod-v1' in dropdown? Or everywhere? Also, how do you expect to replace new value if it appears?

Comment: I have attached a new image of Prometheus. The last item of the query is the return I get when executing the label_values.

Tasks have a specific name within aws.
In prometheus these names are not populated, only the task id appears.

I wanted some way to define the names.

EX: 5YUKKRZ6G5RYDW6UDR4 per task-prod and 75UKQGIYYJMORPCMXP5T4 per task-prod-v1.

Comment: Forgiveness.

It would be in the dropdown menu = DMS Dashboard where I can select the respective task metric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no way of knowing what value should be assigned to each semantic name, obviously it cannot be done through some query.

But since you values are more or less long lived and constant, you can change your variable to type "Custom" and supply its values like this ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qb81K.png)):

```
prod-test : 5YUKKRZ6G5RYDW6UDR4, prod-test-v1 : 75UKQGIYYJMORPCMXP5T4
```

That way in your drop-down you'll see labels, but actual values will be substituted in queries.

In the result, you'll get something like this:
[image]

Take into account, that this will change only the way, how variables shown in drop-down. Legends of graphs will still show labels as they are in Prometheus.

---

If you want to replace labels everywhere, I believe your best shot will be to introduce [relabeling](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config) into configuration of Prometheus, that will replace labels at scraping.

Your relabeling config would look something like this:

```yaml
- source_labels: [replication_task_identifier]
  regex: "5YUKKRZ6G5RYDW6UDR4.+"
  replacement: "prod-prod"
  target_label: "replication_task_name"
  action: "replace"
- source_labels: [replication_task_identifier]
  regex: "75UKQGIYYJMORPCMXP5T4.+"
  replacement: "prod-prod-v1"
  target_label: "replication_task_name"
  action: "replace"
```

More examples on how to do relabeling can be found [here](https://grafana.com/blog/2022/03/21/how-relabeling-in-prometheus-works/).

Comment: The first option worked perfectly!

The second I will test in the future.

Thankssssss =)